# Elixir reuse channel functionalities when only connected to 1 channel

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-channels

I have a lot of channels doing different things like the following:

```
starting_channel
game_channel
food_channel
chat_channel
```

And there's maybe 100 of them.

Everyone starts by joining `starting_channel`. Later I can subscribe the socket to other channel topics and broadcast to different topics accordingly. But the thing is I would not be able to reuse the `handle_in` functionalities in those channels because users don't actually join them in the first place.

For example, let's say room_channel has this handler:

```
def handle_in("show_room_happy_users", _payload, socket) do
  broadcast! socket, "happy_users", Presence.list(socket)
  {:noreply, socket}
end
```

But since you didn't join this channel when you send `show_room_happy_users` message through the `starting_channel` nothing would happen.

Is there a way to achieve this without joining all the channel at once?

Comment: not sure I understand your question. Do you want to use the `handle_in` for a channel that the user did not join? Eg, you join just `starting_channel`, but you want to use a `handle_in` from `game_channel`? Can you please give a more detailed example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @iacobSon I have added an example about what I am trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I don't think that is possible, and I don't see how this would work.  If you create a channel:
`const channel = socket.channel("starting_channel");`
`channel.join`
then in the front-end you listen for that channel reply:
`channel.on(.....)`

You cannot receive an answer without creating a channel.

Comment: So why not adding more `handle_in` functions in the `starting_channel`, if possible, or open and close other channels on demand.

Eg. you open the `room_channel` when you are in the chat, you close it when you leave the chat.

Comment: Because I don't know what channels to join yet..